# How can I return mongoose collection item as JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to return JSON with every specific fields of object of in my collection. But had this error.

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ReplSet'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'coreTopology' -> object with constructor 'ReplSet'
    |     ...
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
```

My GET path

```
router.get('/assignments', auth.required, function (req, res, next) {
  var user = User.findById(req.payload.id);

  var assignments = Assignment.find({ author: user });

  // console.log(assignments)

  if (!user) { return res.sendStatus(401); }

  return res.json({
    assignments: assignments.map(function (assignment) {
      console.log(assignment)
      return assignment.toJSONForTitle();
    })
  });

});
```

My to JSON function

```
AssignmentSchema.methods.toJSONForTitle = function(){
  return {
    title: this.title,
    createdAt: this.createdAt,
  };
};
```

Comment: I see you want to create a instance method in the mongoose.

Comment: `Assignment.find()` should return a `Promise`-like `"thennable"` I don't think it can be `.map`.  Also there is .toJSON() and .toObject() to get a plain object from a document https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON